# Android Studio :Null pointer exception when assembleDebugUnitTest gradle task is run

Tags: android-studio, junit, gradle

I am trying to run a simple JUNIT test for a test class in android studio. Build goes fine. When i try to run the JUNIT test i get the following error

*

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

*

When i dumped the stacktrace i get the following. I am clueless as to why this is happening.

```
:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteAc
tionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTa
skExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecu
tionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskEx
ecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecut
er.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptyS
ourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithN
oActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecut
er.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMost
OnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:31
0)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(Abst
ractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(Abst
ractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTask
PlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java
:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.ja
va:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:3
7)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)

        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:14
9)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessB
uildActionExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.
java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.
java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.
java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSugges
tingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSugges
tingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineAct
ionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineAct
ionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.jav
a:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFacto
ry.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFacto
ry.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.builder.testing.MockableJarGenerator.rewriteClass(MockableJarGenerator.java:134
)
        at com.android.builder.testing.MockableJarGenerator.createMockableJar(MockableJarGenerator.jav
a:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MockableAndroidJarTask.createMockableJar(MockableAn
droidJarTask.groovy:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAct
ion.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAct
ion.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAct
ion.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteAct
ionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteAc
tionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 49 more
```

Test Environment used:

Environment: 1.2.2
SDK Version : API 21
Build tools 22.0.1
Android Plugin version : 1.2.3
Gradle version : 2.5
JDK : 1.7.0_79

Can you please help me out with this? Is there any problem with my setup?

Build Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.krishnaswamyna.testmathsapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:22.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same issue since a couple of weeks. I saw a hint about the issue being about the SDK from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181521).

What worked for me was to simply remove the SDK through the SDK Manager and then reinstalling it. You might also have to clean the project and/or invalidate cashes and restart Android Studio, between removing and reinstalling the SDK.

Comment: I have the same problem, I think there's some bug fix in the latest SDK update. So I update to the latest version or my SDK 19, everything works.

Answer (score 6):

Jus delete the .gradle file in the project

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when i installed the *Android Studio 2.0*.

Uncheck `Enable all test artifacts` in:

> File-> Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployement->Build Tools ->
>   Gradle-> Experimental gradle

**Info**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536967/execution-failed-for-task-mockableandroidjar)

Comment: I confirm that by disabling the *Enable all test artifacts* option I can build my project again.

Answer (score 1):

**Clean the build** and rebuild the app this might work and fix the issue. This gradle errors might come due to some old edited files just do the above said.