# Execution failed for task mockableAndroidJar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, build.gradle

When I try to build application I am getting this exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

This is fragment of stactrace:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.builder.testing.MockableJarGenerator.rewriteClass(MockableJarGenerator.java:126)
        at com.android.builder.testing.MockableJarGenerator.createMockableJar(MockableJarGenerator.java:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MockableAndroidJarTask.createMockableJar(MockableAndroidJarTask.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
```

Configuration: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0`, `buildToolsVersion 23.0.2`, `gradle 2.4`

Cannot figure out whats wrong happening. It used to work and configuration wasn't change for ages. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to uncheck test artifacts option inside:

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Experimental -> Enable all test artifacts in Android projects

Answer (score 0):

I think actual reason on different version:
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
relate to the same version for 
dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

is ok.

Comment: I don't see OP mentioning the support library.

Comment: There is no mention, but the corresponding version number can work